# Haskell dependent, independent variables in lambda function as applied to foldr

Tags: haskell, types, fold, lambda-calculus

Given

```
> foldr (+) 5 [1,2,3,4]
15
```

this second version

```
foldr (\x n -> x + n) 5 [1,2,3,4]
```

also returns `15`. The first thing I don't understand about the second version is how `foldr` knows which variable is associated with the accumulator-seed `5` and which with the list variable's elements `[1,2,3,4]`. In the lambda calculus way, `x` would seem to be the dependent variable and `n` the independent variable. So if this

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ z []     =  z
foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)
```

is `foldr` and these

```
:type foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b

:t +d foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

its type declarations, can I glean, deduce the answer to *"which is dependent and which is independent"* from the type declaration itself? It would seem both examples of `foldr` above must be doing this

```
(+) 1 ((+) 2 ((+) 3 ((+) 4 ((+) 5 0))))
```

I simply guessed the second, lambda function version above, but I don't really understand how it works, whereas the first version with `(+)` breaks down as shown directly above.

Another example would be this

```
length' = foldr (const (1+)) 0
```

where, again, `const` seems to know to "throw out" the incoming list elements and simply increment, starting with the initial accumulator value. This is the same as

```
length' = foldr (\_ acc -> 1 + acc) 0
```

where, again, Haskell knows which of `foldr`'s second and third arguments -- accumulator and list -- to treat as the dependent and independent variable, seemingly by magic. But no, I'm sure the answer lies in the type declaration (which I can't decipher, hence, this post), as well as the lore of lambda calculus, of which I'm a beginner.

**Update**

I've found this

```
reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

and then applying to a list

```
foldl (flip (:)) [] [1,2,3]
foldl (flip (:)) (1:[]) [2,3]
foldl (flip (:)) (2:1:[]) [3]
foldl (flip (:)) (3:2:1:[]) []
. . .
```

Here it's obvious that the order is "accumulator" and then list, and `flip` is flipping the first and second variables, then subjecting them to `(:)`. Again, this

```
reverse = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) []
foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) [] [1,2,3]
foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) (1:[]) [1,2,3]
. . .
```

seems also to rely on order, but in the example from further above

```
length' = foldr (\_ acc -> 1 + acc) 0
foldr (\_ acc -> 1 + acc) 0 [1,2,3]
```

how does it know `0` is the accumulator and is bound to `acc` and not the first (ghost) variable? So as I understand (the first five pages of) lambda calculus, any variable that is "lambda'd," e.g., `\x` is a dependent variable, and all other non-lambda'd variables are independent. Above, the `\_` is associated with `[1,2,3]` and the `acc`, ostensibly the independent variable, is `0`; hence, order *is not* dictating assignment. It's as if `acc` was some keyword that when used always binds to the accumulator, while `x` is always talking about the incoming list members.

Also, what is the "algebra" in the type definition where `t a` is transformed to `[a]`? Is this something from category theory? I see

```
Data.Foldable.toList :: t a -> [a]
```

in the `Foldable` definition. Is that all it is?

Comment: If `t ~ []`, then `t a` is `[] a`, or more convenient `[a]`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dependent" and "independent" here. `f` takes an element of the iterable as its first argument, and the recursive result  (or the seed) as its second.

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand what you're asking here. But comparing the 2 expressions at the start of your question, `(+)` is identical `(\x n -> x + n)`, so it shouldn't be surprising that substituting one for the other has the same effect. Or is the question about not understanding why these two function expressions are the same?

Comment: I'm asking about how Haskell knows which variable is which. `x` for the input list and `n` for the accumulator? Right, so how does Haskell know, relegate this?

Comment: Can you explain what are dependent and independent variables in lambda calculus? I feel you mixing concepts. Also it's a bit odd you that you wrote down the definition of foldr and still missing how in `(\x n -> x + n)` x and n end up bound to the values they do.

Comment: Btw the correct evaluation is `(+) 1 ((+) 2 ((+) 3 ((+) 4 ((+) 5 0))))`, you missed one step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "dependent" you most probably mean *bound* variable.

By "independent" you most probably mean *free* (i.e. not bound) variable.

There are no free variables in `(\x n -> x + n)`. Both `x` and `n` appear to the left of the arrow, `->`, so they are named parameters of this lambda function, *bound* inside its body, to the right of the arrow. Being bound means that each reference to `n`, say, in the function's body is replaced with the reference to the corresponding *argument* when this lambda function is indeed applied to its argument(s).

Similarly both `_` and `acc` are bound in `(\_ acc -> 1 + acc)`'s body. The fact that the *wildcard* is used here, is immaterial. We could just have written `_we_dont_care_` all the same.

The parameters in lambda function definition get "assigned" (also called "bound") the values of the arguments in an application, ***purely positionally***. The first argument will be bound / assigned to the first parameter, the second argument - to the second parameter. Then the lambda function's body will be entered and further reduced according to the rules.

This can be seen a bit differently stating that actually in lambda calculus all functions have only one parameter, and multi-parameter functions are actually nested uni-parameter lambda functions; and that the application is left-associative i.e. nested to the left.

What this actually means is quite simply

```
 (\ x n -> x + n)  5  0
=
 (\ x -> (\ n -> x + n))  5  0
=
((\ x -> (\ n -> x + n))  5)  0
=
         (\ n -> 5 + n)      0
=
                 5 + 0
```

As to how Haskell knows which is which from the type signatures, again, the type variables in the functional types are also positional, with first type variable corresponding to the type of the first expected argument, the second type variable to the second expected argument's type, and so on.

It is *all* purely positional.

Thus, as a matter of purely mechanical and careful substitution, since by the definition of `foldr` it holds that `foldr g 0 [1,2,3] = g 1 (foldr g 0 [2,3]) = ... = g 1 (g 2 (g 3 0))`, we have

```
foldr (\x n -> x + n) 0 [1,2,3]
=
      (\x n -> x + n) 1 ( (\x n -> x + n) 2 ( (\x n -> x + n) 3 0 ))
=
(\x -> (\n -> x + n)) 1 ( (\x n -> x + n) 2 ( (\x n -> x + n) 3 0 ))
=
       (\n -> 1 + n)    ( (\x n -> x + n) 2 ( (\x n -> x + n) 3 0 ))
=
              1 +      ( (\x n -> x + n)  2 ( (\x n -> x + n) 3 0 ))
=
              1 +    ( (\x (\n -> x + n)) 2 ( (\x n -> x + n) 3 0 ))
=
              1 +          (\n -> 2 + n)    ( (\x n -> x + n) 3 0 )
=
              1 +                (2 +        (\x n -> x + n)  3 0 )
=
              1 +                (2 +   (\x -> (\n -> x + n)) 3 0 )
=
              1 +                (2 +          (\n -> 3 + n)    0 )
=
              1 +                (2 +               ( 3 +       0))
```

In other words, there is absolutely no difference between `(\x n -> x + n)` and `(+)`.

As for that `t` in `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`, what that means is that given a certain type `T a`, if `instance Foldable T` exists, then the type becomes `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> T a -> b`, when it's used with a value of type `T a`.

One example is `Maybe a` and thus `foldr (g :: a -> b -> b) (z :: b) :: Maybe a -> b`.

Another example is `[] a` and thus `foldr (g :: a -> b -> b) (z :: b) :: [a] -> b`.

---

(*edit:*) So let's focus on lists. What does it mean for a function `foo` to have that type,

```
foo :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

? It means that it expects an argument of type `a -> b -> b`, i.e. a function, let's call it `g`, so that

```
foo :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
g   ::  a -> b -> b
-------------------------------------
foo    g             :: b -> [a] -> b
```

which is itself a function, expecting of some argument `z` of type `b`, so that

```
foo :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
g   ::  a -> b -> b
z   ::                  b
-------------------------------------
foo    g                z :: [a] -> b
```

which is itself a function, expecting of some argument `xs` of type `[a]`, so that

```
foo :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
g   ::  a -> b -> b
z   ::                  b
xs  ::                       [a]
-------------------------------------
foo    g                z     xs :: b
```

And what could such function `foo g z` do, given a list, say, `[x]` (i.e. `x :: a`, `[x] :: [a]`)?

```
foo g z [x] = b where
```

We need to produce a `b` value, but how? Well, `g :: a -> b -> b` produces a function `b -> b` given an value of type `a`. Wait, we have that!

```
   f = g x     -- f :: b -> b
```

and what does it help us? Well, we have `z :: b`, so

```
   b = f z
```

And what if it's `[]` we're given? We don't have any `a`s then at all, but we have a `b` type value, `z` -- so instead of the above we'd just define

```
   b = z
```

And what if it's `[x,y]` we're given? We'll do the same `f`-building trick, twice:

```
   f1 = g x     -- f1 :: b -> b
   f2 = g y     -- f2 :: b -> b
```

and to produce `b` we have many options now: it's `z`! or maybe, it's `f1 z`!? or `f2 z`? But the most general thing we can do, making use of *all* the data we have access to, is

```
   b = f1 (f2 z)
```

for a *right*-fold (...... or,

```
   b = f2 (f1 z)
```

for a *left*).

And if we substitute and simplify, we get

```
foldr g z [] = z
foldr g z [x] = g x z         --  =  g x (foldr g z [])
foldr g z [x,y] = g x (g y z)     --  =  g x (foldr g z [y])
foldr g z [x,y,w] = g x (g y (g w z))  --  =  g x (foldr g z [y,w])
```

A pattern emerges.

Etc., etc., etc.

---

A sidenote: `b` is a bad naming choice, as is usual in Haskell. `r` would be much much better -- a mnemonic for "recursive result".

Another mnemonic is the order of `g`'s arguments: `a -> r -> r` suggests, nay dictates, that a list's element `a` comes as a first argument; `r` the recursive result comes second (the Result of Recursively processing the Rest of the input list -- *recursively*, thus *in the same manner*); and the overall result is then produced by this "step"-function, `g`.

And that's the essence of recursion: recursively process self-similar sub-part(s) of the input structure, and complete the processing by a simple *single step*:

```
           a                         a
             :                         `g`
               [a]                         r
          -------------             -------------
                   [a]                         r

      [a]
     a   [a]
    --------
    (x : xs)       -> r 
         xs -> r
   ----------------------
   ( x  ,      r ) -> r        --- or, equivalently,   x -> r -> r
```

Comment: You say *purely positional* and yes, in your first example this is true. But then in your second example it seems `[1,2,3]` (the second argument) has jumped ahead of `0` (the first argument) and then `(\x n -> x + n)` is applied to each of the three members. So if we are only looking at your first example, then yes, position dictates binding. But what I'm now guessing is `foldr` has rules that are applied (switch and spread argument #2), *then* apply the beta reduction. Bottom line: In your second example/breakdown `foldr` takes things from step 1 to 2, then we start beta reduction. Right?

Comment: `foldr` is defined so that `foldr g 0 [1,2,3] = g 1 (foldr g 0 [2,3])`. so we do that. then, `g` comes into play, since it is at the head. `g` is `(\x n -> x + n)` i.e. `g x n = x + n`. I could've applied that, but I went with smaller steps, using the lambda function, as you seem to have questions about how _that_ works. in the end, either we reduce the _two_, _nested_, one-parameter lambdas step after step, or if we'd used the definition with the `=` sign, the end result is the same. so yes, we did beta-reduction there, two of them, since there are two arguments there. _both_ of them are ...

Comment: ... "lambda'd" as you called it, since both of them are _to the left_ of the arrow. _both_ of them are "formal parameters" of that lambda functions. not just the one after the \. BTW, in JS they don't write that backslash, and instead they just write `(n x => n + x)`. this is the same as when in lambda calculus we write it with the dot, `(\n. \x. n+x)` (I'm typing the backslash instead of the Greek letter lambda there)

Comment: and in lambda calculus as well, `(\n. \x. n+x)` == `(\n. (\x. n+x))` == `(\n x. n+x)` are all just different ways to write down the same thing.

Comment: Takeaway is `foldr g 0 [1,2,3] = g 1 (foldr g 0 [2,3])` etc. _then_ the beta reduction starts. I didn't realize `foldr` did this initial arranging. I was simply looking at the `(\x n -> x + n) 0 [1,2,3]` part and getting confused about how the positional binding didn't seem to jive. Thank you very much.

Comment: in Haskell the reduction is always driven from the head, since it is lazy. first it's `foldr` at the head, so we reduce _that_. then `g` comes to the head. etc. accept? more questions? :)

Comment: Exactly. `foldr` first, then the `g` beta reduction stuff. Hopefully my confusion-enlightenment arc can help others.

Comment: I'll give you the green check, but write up an answer myself. I'd like to weave in the type definition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `foldr` itself knows this by definition. It was defined in such way that its function argument accepts the accumulator as 2nd argument.

Just like when you write a `div x y = ...` function you are free to use `y` as dividend.

Maybe you got confused by the fact that `foldr` and `foldl` has swapped arguments in the accumulator funtions?

Answer (score 0):

As Steven Leiva says [here](https://medium.com/@StevenLeiva1/haskell-book-chapter-10-folding-lists-3e9e82ce5201), a `foldr` (1) takes a list and replaces the cons operators `(:)` with the given function and (2) replaces the last empty list `[]` with the accumulator-seed, which is what the definition of `foldr` says it will do

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ z []     =  z
foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)
```

So de-sugared [1,2,3] is

```
(:) 1 ((:) 2 ((:) 3 []))
```

and the recursion is in effect replacing the `(:)` with `f`, and as we see in `foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)`, the `z` seed value is going along for the ride until the base case where it is substituted for the `[]`, fulfilling (1) and (2) above.

My first confusion was seeing this

```
foldr (\x n -> x + n) 0 [1,2,3]
```

and not understanding it would be expanded out, per definition above, to

```
(\x n -> x + n) 1 ((\x n -> x + n) 2 ((\x n -> x + n) 3 0 ))
```

Next, due to a weak understanding of how the actual beta reduction would progress, I didn't understand the second-to-third step below

```
(\x -> (\n -> x + n)) 1 ...
(\n -> 1 + n) ...
1 + ...
```

That second-to-third step is lambda calculus being bizarre all right, but is at the root of why `(+)` and `(\x n -> x + n)` are the same thing. I don't think it's pure lambda calculus addition, but it (verbosely) mimics addition in recursion. I probably need to jump back into lambda calculus to really grasp why `(\n -> 1 + n)` turns into `1 +`

My worse mental block was thinking I was looking at some sort of eager evaluation inside the parentheses first

```
foldr ((\x n -> x + n) 0 [1,2,3,4])
```

where the three arguments to `foldr` would interact first, i.e., `0` would be bound to the `x` and the list member to the `n`

```
(\x n -> x + n) 0 [1,2,3,4]
0 + 1
```

. . . then I didn't know what to think. Totally wrong-headed, even though, as Will Ness points out above, beta reduction is positional in binding arguments to variables. But, of course, I left out the fact that Haskell currying means we follow the expansion of `foldr` first.

I still don't fully understand the type definition

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

other than to comment/guess that the first `a` and the `[a]` mean `a` is of the type of the members of the incoming list and that the `(a -> b -> b)` is a prelim-microcosm of what `foldr` will do, i.e., it will take an argument of the incoming list's type (in our case the elements of the list?) then another object of type `b` and produce an object `b`. So the seed argument is of type `b` and the whole process will finally produce something of type `b`, also the given function argument will take an `a` and ultimately give back an object `b` which actually might be of type `a` as well, and in fact is in the above example with integers... IOW, I don't really have a firm grasp of the type definition...

Comment: there is no parentheses in `foldr (\x n -> x + n) 0 [1,2,3]` closing together the arguments. application associates to the left, so it is `( ( ( foldr (\x n -> x + n) ) 0 ) [1,2,3] )`. Maybe I'll write another answer dealing with the type and how it corresponds to the definition, later....

Comment: (for the benefit of a casual reader: I've since edited my answer with more explanations)